# Does Axios support 'keepalive' functionality same as the native fetch()?

Tags: javascript, browser, axios, fetch

Can Axios be configured to keep requests alive after a browser page is closed? Native fetch() accepts `keepalive` flag to enable this functionality, while I haven't found any similar in Axios documentation.

> **keepalive**
> The keepalive option can be used to allow the request to outlive the page. Fetch with the keepalive flag is a replacement for the Navigator.sendBeacon() API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can do this with axios if you create your own axios instance.

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'},
  httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
});
```

[Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) docs can guide you a bit more.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but looks like we are talking about different things here.  Axios `keepAlive` defines a custom agent to be used when performing http and https requests in NodeJS while I was asking about `keepalive` feature of the native `fetch()` which allows browser to complete the request even when page was closed.

Comment: I apologize! I think I may have read your question too quickly.